# Render not including light on output?

Tags: light

My blender session looks like so:[image]

im in render view and can see the spot light Im using. When I export to an image however I get this very flat image and no light happening? why is this happening?: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you accidentally turn off that plane in render setting?

[image]

The preview in 3D view doesn't follow render visible setting in the outliner

Toggle the icon on again and see if the problem is resolved.